# Prove that if for all $g$ such that $∫_a^bg(x)dx=0$ also $∫_a^bg(x)\cdot f(x)dx=0$, then $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose:

$\forall g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: ∫_a^bg(x)dx=0\Rightarrow∫_a^bf(x)\cdot g(x)=0$

**Prove that f is a constant function.**

This is a problem from my calculus II homework that I've been trying to solve, but I don't even know where to start.
I tried to prove this by contradiction and by using the definition of Reimann or Darboux sums, but I just don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Without loss of generality, suppose that $a=0$ and $b =2\pi$. Then expand $f$ into a Fourier series.

Comment: What hypothesis do you have on $g$ maps?

Comment: I haven't learned the Fourier series. The proof is supposed to be using only the basic theorems on integration, and the Reimann/Darboux/Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: Try only functions g that have two values and have integral 0, e.g. $g(x) = 1$ for $ x < (a+b)/2$ and $-1$ for $x \geqslant (a+b)/2$ . Now there are a lot more functions like this and with them you can show that f is constant.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/347441/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042507/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $f$ is not constant: it exists $a \le c \lt d \le b$ such that $f(c) \neq f(d)$. Without loss of generality, you can suppose $f(c) \lt f(d)$.

As $f$ is supposed to be continuous, you can find two intervals $I_c, I_d \subseteq [a,b]$  of same lengths such that $c \in I_c$, $d \in I_d$ and $f(x) \lt \frac{f(c) + f(d)}{2} \lt f(y)$ for any $(x,y) \in I_c \times I_d$.

Now consider the map $g$ equal to $-1$ on $I_c$, $1$ on $I_d$ and $0$ elsewhere. You have $\int_a^b g(x) dx=0$ but $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx \gt 0$. A contradiction.

Comment: This works. Thank you!